# The numeric value in span tag not showing during web scrapping using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping.

I am trying to download the Net Long position from https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment site. The value is situated in div with class 'dfx-technicalSentimentCard__netLongContainer' and span attribute 'data-value'.

[image]

My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment'

all_pages_reviews = []
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')

rev_div = soup.findAll("span",attrs={"class","dfx-rateDetail__percentageInfoText font-weight-bold"})

print(rev_div)
```

This gives rev_div as "bs4.element.ResultSet" with following output:

```
</span>, <span class="dfx-rateDetail__percentageInfoText font-weight-bold" data-market-id="GBPUSD" data-sort-column="sentiment-long" data-stream-type="sentiment" data-type="long-value-info" data-value="--">

</span>, <span class="dfx-rateDetail__percentageInfoText font-weight-bold" data-market-id="FR40" data-sort-column="sentiment-short" data-stream-type="sentiment" data-type="short-value-info" data-value="--">
```

[image]

The problem is instead of a numeric value '--' is shown for 'data_value'.

My goal here is to find 'data-value' as per 'data-market-id' ('GBPUSD', 'FR40').

Any lead will be highly appreciated.

Comment: this values get data from js, may be from this [API](https://www.dailyfx.com/api/events), in this case better use selenium

Comment: You need javascript, because if you disable javascript in your browser there are no data inside data-value. Try to use selenium or playwright, they use real browser and render javascript.